# How to split MS Access lengthy form into multiple pages?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am using MS Access and I'd like to split a lengthy form into multiple pages. It'd be better if I can use 'next' and 'previous' buttons to navigate within the same form through multiple pages.
I'm using MS Office 2016. I can't move my PageBreak because I've reached the limit of the form :/

[image]
Any help would be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0):

Insert a *PageBreak* in the form:

[image: PageBreak]

Browsing is done with *PageUp* and *PageDown*.

Comment: I can't move de PageBreak and move to the nextPage, I've edited my question with a picture. Thanks

Comment: If you place the pagebreak that close to the bottom, there will be nothing to browse to.

Comment: I tried to insert the PageBreak not that close to the bottom but I still have the same display. What I want is to have a second page when I reach the limit of the first page of the form. Can you please make me a screenshot of what I am sence to see after inserting the PageBreak? Thanks

Comment: Not much on this, but I located [Which page am I on?](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/203267-page-am-i)